# How to formulate this logic using only if statement?

Tags: java

I need to formulate a logic using if statement using these facts.

- The charge for all signs is a minimum of $35.00.
- The first five    letters or numbers are included in the minimum
  charge; there is a $4    charge for each additional character.
- If the sign is made of oak, add    $20.00. No charge is added for
  pine.
- Black or white characters are    included in the minimum charge;
  there is an additional $15 charge for    gold-leaf lettering.

You need to declare variables for the following, and initialize them where specified.

- A variable for the cost of the sign initialized to 0.00.
- A variable for the color of the characters initialized to "gold".
- A variable for the wood type initialized with the value "oak".
- A variable for the number of characters initialized with the value 8.

My problem is with the 2nd fact. I just can't seem to formulate its logic.

This is what I made so far.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    JOptionPane jo = new JOptionPane();
    double minCharge = 35.00;
    double signCost = 0.00;
    String charColor = "gold";
    String woodType = "oak";
    int charNum = 8;

    String signName =jo.showInputDialog("Enter the sign name");
    String signCharColor =jo.showInputDialog("Enter the character color");
    String typeOfWood =jo.showInputDialog("Enter the type of wood to be made");

    signCost = minCharge;

    if(signCharColor.equalsIgnoreCase(charColor))
        signCost += 15;

    if(typeOfWood.equalsIgnoreCase(woodType))
        signCost += 20;

    if(signName.length() > 5)
        signCost =  ;

    String hold= "\n| The charge for this sign is $"+signCost+"|";
    jo.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(hold));

     }
}
```

Comment: Try a few examples. If the sign is "Abracadabra", how much extra would you pay for it? If it's "Zebra", how much? If it's "Thinker", how much? Pay attention to how you do the calculation yourself, and you'll be able to find the logic.

Comment: Unrelated: never do if/while/for ... without { braces } for your loop body. It is so easy to do `if (a) ; bla` and being surprised that bla happens all the time because you put that ; after the condition.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you accepted the answer that leaves a bit of work to you, instead of the one that drops all the code. Nonetheless; in case you decide to delete the question ... go for it. I dont mind deleting my answer in case that thing being around prevents you from deleting the question. In any case, i gave some compensation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets see:

> The first five letters or numbers are included in the minimum charge; there is a $4 charge for each additional character.

In pseudo-code:

```
if sign-length <= 5:
  charge stays the same
else:
  charge = charge + (sign-length - 5) * rate-per-character
```

Should get you going ...

Answer (score 0):

> The first five letters or numbers are included in the minimum charge;

So check the length of the string

> there is a $4 charge for each additional character.

Multiply out the additional charge

```
if (signName.length() > 5)  {
    signCost += 4*(signName.length() - 5); 
}
```